# Dollar Sign Character in Multiline Strings

Tags: string, kotlin, templates, multiline

What is the cleanest method for adding a `$` character in a string literal?

The best solution I've come up with so far is `"""${"$"}..."""`, which looks ugly to me.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To escape the dollar sign inside a string literal, use the backslash character:

```
"\$"
```

To escape it in a *raw* string literal (`"""..."""`), the workaround you provided is indeed the easiest solution at the moment. There's an issue in the bug tracker, which you can star and/or vote for: [KT-2425](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2425).

Answer (score 13):

**In current Kotlin 1.0 (and betas)** you can just escape with backslash `"\$"`

This passing unit test proves the cases:

```
@Test public fun testDollar() {
    val dollar = '$'

    val x1 = "\$100.00"
    val x2 = "${"$"}100.00"
    val x3 = """${"$"}100.00"""
    val x4 = "${dollar}100.00"
    val x5 = """${dollar}100.00"""

    assertEquals(x5, x1)
    assertEquals(x5, x2)
    assertEquals(x5, x3)
    assertEquals(x5, x4)

    // you cannot backslash escape in """ strings, therefore:

    val odd = """\$100.00""" // creates "\$100.00" instead of "$100.00"
    // assertEquals(x5, odd) would fail
}
```

All versions make a string `"$100.00"` except for the one odd case at the end.

Comment: well, now all options are visible ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov That's why there's a solution with x3.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't look like you pasted your code correctly as you only have 3 double quotes.

Anyhow, the best way to do this is to just escape the dollar sign as follows:

```
"\$"
```

Comment: You cannot escape inside a raw string, which I believe is the purpose of the question.

Comment: @jkschneider you can in current Kotlin, the question and your comment are out of date for the current state of Kotlin.  This answer is correct.

Comment: @JaysonMinard no, you cannot do that in a raw string, please read the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov yes, problem with my brain function at 4AM

Answer (score 1):

To get literal dollar signs shows in multi-line strings, you can do the below

I'm sorry for my sins:

```
val nonInterpedValue = "\${someTemplate}"
val multiLineWithNoninterp = """
        Hello
        $nonInterpedValue
        World
""".trimIndent()
```

As mentioned elsewhere, this is the workaround because right now you can't use dollar signs inside multi-line strings. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2425

( I needed this to get Groovy's Template Engine working: https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-template-engines)