# Not getting a new line in kotlin text view on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

fun SubmitOrder(view: View) {

```
    /* pricing of coffee */
    val total = quantity * 5
    val s: String = ("$$total.00")
    money.text = ("Total : $s\nThank You!").toString()

    //This is calling On click listener
    Toast.makeText(this, "order_Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

In this code, I need a new line before Thank You! in money.text but I am not getting any new line I am new in android development so,  am not able to point out the mistake.

Comment: Use a custom layout or have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888664/android-toast-doesnt-fit-text

Comment: Do you have any maxLines=1 or lines=1 or singleLine=true property set for the TextView?

Answer (score 0):

Let's go thru your code line by line:

---

```
val s: String = ("$$total.00")
```

- `s` is a bad variable name, as it's not descriptive at all
- you don't need the (braces)
- the `:String` here is optional. In such an obvious case i would emit it.
- A `$` is a sign to the kotlin compiler to include the following variable. Therefore, you can't use the $ when you mean "US-Dollar". See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690724/dollar-sign-character-in-strings) on how to escape it
- While `".00"` works, it's no good style. I suggest you use string formatting as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086291/format-in-kotlin-string-templates).
- can be written as `val s = "\$ ${String.format("%.2f", total)}"`
- you should wherever possible use [string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource), but thats out of the scope of this answer

---

```
money.text = ("Total : $s\nThank You!").toString()
```

- this is correct, but unnecessary verbose:
- `"Total : $s\nThank You!"` is already a string, so there's no need to `.toString()`
- braces are not needed
- can be written as `money.text = "Total : $s\nThank You!"`